# Android - Mockito cannot mock this class: class android.content.Context

Tags: android, unit-testing, exception, mockito

We had Mockito version 2.18.3. Now I upgraded to 3.5.13.
Also Robolectric version is upgraded from 3.8 to 4.4.

So half of 700 tests started failing on different reasons. One of them is as below that mockito can't create Context class.

Other classes it could not mock now, for ex, are many interfaces of our codebase, classes, android.app.Activity, android.location.Location.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
net.abc.def.MyTest > FirstTest FAILED
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Mockito cannot mock this class: class android.content.Context.

If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 1.8
JVM vendor name    : Private Build
JVM vendor version : 25.265-b01
JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~16.04-b01
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Linux
OS version         : 4.4.0-57-generic


You are seeing this disclaimer because Mockito is configured to create inlined mocks.
You can learn about inline mocks and their limitations under item #39 of the Mockito class javadoc.

Underlying exception : org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Could not modify all classes [class android.content.Context]
    at net.abc.def.MyTest.onSetUp(FirstTest.java:51)

    Caused by:
    org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: Could not modify all classes [class android.content.Context]
        at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:153)
        at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:366)
        at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:175)
        at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:377)
        ... 1 more

        Caused by:
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
        Byte Buddy could not instrument all classes within the mock's type hierarchy

        This problem should never occur for javac-compiled classes. This problem has been observed for classes that are:
         - Compiled by older versions of scalac
         - Classes that are part of the Android distribution
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.triggerRetransformation(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:265)
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:212)
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:46)
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator$1.call(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:43)
            at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:153)
            at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:366)
            at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:175)
            at net.bytebuddy.TypeCache$WithInlineExpunction.findOrInsert(TypeCache.java:377)
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.mockClass(TypeCachingBytecodeGenerator.java:36)
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.createMockType(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:379)
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.doCreateMock(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:339)
            at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.createMock(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:318)
            at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:52)
            at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:61)
            at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1949)
            at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1860)
            ... 1 more

            Caused by:
            java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: android/os/Bundle has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 53.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
                at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
                at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
                at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
                at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
                at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
                at net.bytebuddy.description.method.MethodList$ForLoadedMethods.<init>(MethodList.java:109)
                at net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$ForLoadedType.getDeclaredMethods(TypeDescription.java:8715)
                at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.InstrumentedType$Factory$Default$1.represent(InstrumentedType.java:416)
                at net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy.redefine(ByteBuddy.java:782)
                at net.bytebuddy.ByteBuddy.redefine(ByteBuddy.java:757)
                at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.transform(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:364)
                at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
                at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
                at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses0(Native Method)
                at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.retransformClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:144)
                at org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineBytecodeGenerator.triggerRetransformation(InlineBytecodeGenerator.java:261)
                ... 16 more
```

Comment: `If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.`

Comment: have done, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We had 2 year old gradle version which was 3.3.1. So, when I tried to raise gradle version directly to the latest 4.x, some issues while running unit tests have popped up..so had to raise mockito also and that ended up with this problem.

Had become messy and did not know how to fix that.

Just changed the approach - started raising the gradle version one by one instead of jumping directly to the latest from such a old one. And that went smooth and all good now.

So if you are in the same situation..raise versions one by one instead of hopping long.